# Woocommerc rename field name in admin Customer billing address

Tags: woocommerce

How to rename of label "Phone" in admin area of Customer billing address?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `woocommerce_customer_meta_fields` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', 'filter_add_customer_meta_fields', 10, 1 );
function filter_add_customer_meta_fields( $args ) {
    $args['billing']['fields']['billing_phone'] = array(
        'label'       => __( 'My custom text', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return $args;
}
```